# Php script to automate Twitter Posts - Guidance

Tags: php

Hi I have a bit of PHP experience and I am tasked with making an automated script to post to twitter account. We have a RSS feed which is updated when we make a new article entry into the site, and would like to pass this info to the twitter script.

I am speaking about the process of taking the latest RSS feed and moving it to the twitter posting. I know how to automatically tweet with PHP not sure how to get the updated RSS feed aspect...

Just looking for some advice, hints to try to figure out how I should approach this... Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you use a service like [TwitterFeed](http://twitterfeed.com/)?

Comment: Have you tried to implement a solution yet? What happened, what failed..?

Answer (score -1):

Here are some articles on php to twitter via [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=post+to+twitter+with+php).

If you are having a problem with a particular aspect of this, please provide some code that isn't working, or things you have tried that haven't worked. The more info you can provide, the easier it is for people to help!

Comment: May I refer you to the following discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links

Comment: @Hollertrain again, google was able to help: http://paulstamatiou.com/stammy-script-rss-to-twitter-using-php/

If you want more specific help, maybe post some code that you're having trouble with; or post what you have tried and didn't work, etc. The more specific the better.

Comment: Not an answer.  99% of the questions posted here can be answered via the answer "Google."  Don't post answers just for the sake of posting answers.

Comment: @all: sorry, didn't mean to come off sounding like a jerk. It just seems like it would be easier to help with a some more information.

Comment: @stormdrain, it's not that you sounded like a jerk, as such, it just appears dismissive of the OP's question to post a link to Google results (if you don't feel the question is valid it's probably best not to answer). Unfortunately, despite the edit/revision your answer still reads like a comment, more than anything else. Though I agree: the OP *should* try and outline what's already been tried, and provide more details.

Comment: @ricebowl: duly noted. I will be more conscious of my posts in the future. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @stormdrain: no worries, and thank *you* for having the strength of character to take the criticism with good grace. (I remember flame-wars back on Slashdot that could rage for *years* for, and with, much less reason...) =)